# I am always getting the data of my last row instead of the row clicked inside listview using CursorAdapter

Tags: android

I managed to make a TextView to act as a clickable inside listview that is being populated using an extended version of CursorAdapter.

I am normally using the newView and the bindView of the CursorAdapter class.

My problem is that, whenever I click the textview (acting as a button in my case), I can not get the chunk of data (id, name, surname, etc) from the row. I always am getting the last rows data (given I am trying to get the data from fetching the cursor passed by from the activity).

Shall I use the viewTag and setTag methods or so ? Any insights is highly appreciated.

```
public class myCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter
{      
    String id;

    public myCursorAdapter (Context context, Cursor c, int status)
    {
            super(context, c, status);
    }

     protected static class RowViewHolder
     {
       public TextView resentTV;
     }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent)
    {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

            RowViewHolder holder = new RowViewHolder();
            holder.resentTV = (TextView) retView.findViewById(R.id.resendTextViewVIEW);
            holder.resentTV.setOnClickListener(mOnTitleClickListener);

            return retView;
    }

     @Override
    public void bindView(View vi, Context context, Cursor cursor)
    {
            DbAllHelper db = DbAllHelper.getInstance(context);

            TextView nameTV = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.nameTextViewVIEW);
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(2)));
            nameTV.setText(name);

            TextView resendTV = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.resendTextViewVIEW);
            resendTV.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            String id= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(0)));

    }

    private OnClickListener mOnTitleClickListener = new OnClickListener()
    {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                    //do what you have to do here;
                    //I am always getting the ID of the last row here, instead of the one pressed.
            }
    };
```

}

Comment: you will use `resentTV.setTag` and inside onClick use `v.getTag` to get clicked TextView or other values on TextView click

Comment: can you provide code ?

Comment: why you are calling `resendTV.setVisibility(View.GONE);` in bindView?

Comment: because sometimes I dont show it (depending on a method that is not appearing in the code as I removed it before copy pasting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setTag` and `getTag` method for getting clicked TextView value in onClick method:

```
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent)
{
  holder.resentTV = (TextView)retView.findViewById(R.id.resendTextViewVIEW);
  String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(2)));
  holder.resentTV.setTag(name);
  // do same for other values..
  holder.resentTV.setOnClickListener(mOnTitleClickListener);

  return retView;
}
```

Now get value from v:

```
private OnClickListener mOnTitleClickListener = new OnClickListener()
{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
           String name=(String)v.getTag();
           Log.v("TAG","Name :"+name);
         }
};
```

Comment: @tony: if not work then try same code in bindView instead of newView

Comment: thanks a lot mate ! it worked perfect !!! what Im doing im taking the ID using the set tage method and utilizing it in an asynctask (not showing in code).. but I want to when the async is done, remove a the textview from the row,, how is that possible ? notifyDataSetChanged() is not working from inside the cursorAdapter

Comment: @tony9099: please post new question with related part of code because we need related code to provide solution for next issue

Comment: done !! have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28255308/can-not-remove-edittext-from-a-row-from-inside-cursoradapter

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as best as I can see it, is that you're using the same `OnClickListener` for every view. In a `ListView`, the `newView` and `bindView` methods will be called for each row, but if you use the same click listener on each of them it will be hard to determine which view got clicked.

Fortunately, `ListView` itself has an `OnItemClickListener` that you can set on it that will give you more data about which view in your list just got selected (item id, position #, etc.). To use that, call `setOnItemClickListener` on your `ListView` with your `OnItemClickListener` and you should be all set.

Code:

```
class TonysActivity extends Activity {
    ListView listView;
    myCursorAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_layout_with_list_view);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        adapter = new myCursorAdapter(this, getCursor(), getStatus());

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long itemId) {
                // handle your item being clicked here
            }
        }
    }

    private Cursor getCursor() {
        // get your cursor for your data
    }

    private int getStatus() {
        // get your status for your adapter
    }
}
```

Comment: if you call `onclicklistner` in `getView()` of any extender baseadapter it will work fine. Its your assumption ?

Comment: sddamico can you provide some code ? Im kinda lost in the generics. I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry, @MurtazaHussain, I don't think I understand your question? setting the `OnClickListener` in `getVew()` will work, obviously, but it will be very difficult to determine which view got clicked because they're all receiving the same callback.

Comment: sddamico thanks a lot pal. but I have a clickable textview inside the row that I want to run the code whenever that specific textview is clicked and not the whole row.

Comment: Offcourse you have to set identity tag to that row.

Comment: im taking the ID using the set tage method and utilizing it in an asynctask (not showing in code).. but I want to when the async is done, remove a the textview from the row,, how is that possible ? notifyDataSetChanged() is not working from inside the cursorAdapter

Answer (score 0):

why not set the listener on the list? Textviews need extra padding to make them easier to click see below a solution using a listener attached to the list

// refactored class

```
public class myCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter{
    String id;

    public myCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int status) {
        super(context, c, status);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View vi, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // Do you need DbALLHelper
        DbAllHelper db = DbAllHelper.getInstance(context);

        TextView nameTV = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.nameTextViewVIEW);
        String name = cursor.getString(2);
        nameTV.setText(name);

        TextView resendTV = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.resendTextViewVIEW);
        resendTV.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // Do you need id
        String id = cursor.getString(0);

    }
}
```

// below is the listener you can set on the list

```
yourList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor)adapter.getItem(i);
        String id = cursor.getString(0);
        String name = cursor.getString(2);
    }
});
```

Comment: kevin that is correct, but I have a clickable textview inside the row that I want to run the code whenever that specific textview is clicked and not the whole row.

Comment: Assuming you have set clickable for your textviews to true, then setTag() with the class you want to hold the data and then getTag in the listener, you could instead make the CursorAdapter implement View.OnClickListener, and use holder.resentTV.setOnClickListener(this) makes things cleaner.

Comment: kevin, I would highly appreciate it if you can translate that into code. I have been on this for 5 hours and my heads gonna bam !

Comment: See a new answer to your question below :) excuse the rough draft, just implement that flow hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class myCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter implement View.OnClickListener{
String id;

public myCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int status) {
    super(context, c, status);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View vi, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    // Do you need DbALLHelper
    DbAllHelper db = DbAllHelper.getInstance(context);

    TextView nameTV = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.nameTextViewVIEW);
    String name = cursor.getString(2);
    nameTV.setText(name);

    TextView resendTV = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.resendTextViewVIEW);
    resendTV.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // Do you need id
        String id = cursor.getString(0);

      // Assuming you going to use values from 
      //db setTag with class containing data here
      AClassContainingData aClass = new AClassContainingData()
      aClass.name = "USE ANY CLASS"
      resentTV.setTag(AClassContainingData)
      resentTV.setOnClickListener(this)

    }

@Override
public void onClick(View view){
  AClassContainingData aClass = (AClassContainingData)view.getTag()
  // DO ANYTHING ELSE
}

}
```

Comment: thanks a lot mate ! im taking the ID using the set tage method and utilizing it in an asynctask (not showing in code).. but I want to when the async is done, remove a the textview from the row,, how is that possible ? notifyDataSetChanged() is not working from inside the cursorAdapter

Comment: With pleasure , you could create an interface with one method and let your fragment or activity implement it and pass the activity or fragment an the interface argument in the adapters constructor.

Comment: Kevin, I think thats a long way, anything easier ? I posted a new question via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28255308/can-not-remove-edittext-from-a-row-from-inside-cursoradapter have a look