# Can not remove EditText from a row from inside CursorAdapter

Tags: android

In the below code, I have managed to get an `EditText` to function inside a row. Also managed to make the button get clicked (without the whole row being clicked) and fire an `AsyncTask` whenever the click happens.
The code runs good and does the job. However, whenever I press the button I want it to be removed in the `onPostExecute` of the async.

(in the below code, I do not post the `setTag` and the `viewTag` stuff. Do not mind it, as I can get which row was clicked when the button was clicked.)
So please focus on making the `EditText` invisible rather than that.

```
public class myCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter
{      
String id;

public myCursorAdapter (Context context, Cursor c, int status)
{
        super(context, c, status);
}

 protected static class RowViewHolder
 {
   public TextView resentTV;
 }

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent)
{
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

        RowViewHolder holder = new RowViewHolder();
        holder.resentTV = (TextView) retView.findViewById(R.id.resendTextViewVIEW);
        holder.resentTV.setOnClickListener(mOnTitleClickListener);

        return retView;
}

 @Override
public void bindView(View vi, Context context, Cursor cursor)
{
        DbAllHelper db = DbAllHelper.getInstance(context);

        TextView nameTV = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.nameTextViewVIEW);
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(2)));
        nameTV.setText(name);

        TextView resendTV = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.resendTextViewVIEW);
        resendTV.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        String id= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(0)));

}

private OnClickListener mOnTitleClickListener = new OnClickListener()
{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
                new myAsynck().execute(); //does network stuff
        }
};



class MySync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args)
    {   
        //do some network stuff
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String str)
    {
       //problem here
       //remove the EditText of the row that had the button that caused this async to run
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to remove the EditText only, or the whole row from the adapter?

Comment: Just that edittext from that specific row. Not the entire row !!

Comment: marcus what bonnyz answered below worked ! have a look at his answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple solution. Just create a slightly different `AsyncTask` and pass to it the `View` which you want to hide after the task execution.
The following implementation uses a `WeakReference<View>` to avoid possible leaks:

```
   class MySync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {

        WeakReference<View> toHide;

        public MySync(View v){
            super();
            toHide = new WeakReference<View>(v);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args)
        {   
            //do some network stuff
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String str)
        {
            if(toHide != null && toHide.get() != null)
                toHide.get().setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

Now, invoke your new `AsyncTask` passing the **target `View`**:

```
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       new myAsynck(v).execute(); //does network stuff
   }
```

If you need to hide a `View` which is different from the *target View* (which is, in your case, the button), you can use something like this to find another child starting from the parent:

```
    ViewGroup vg = ((ViewGroup)toHide.get().getParent());
    View otherView = vg.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    otherView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Bonnyz, that did it im very grateful for your efforts. do you mind doing a little explanation why you used weakreference and implemented this method ? thanks :))

Comment: @tony9099 sure. As habit, I preferer to never store direct references to `View` and `Context` objects outside their natural scope because they are often cause of leaks. In this case, if the `AsyncTask` is created somewhere and never used it will hold a reference to a View; if the `AsyncTask` is running while the whole layout is changing (which is possible), the referenced `View` could not be GC-ed and so on...